# How to kill all background processes in a shell with CONTROL+C

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, background-process

I'm new to shell scripting.
I have the following task to solve:
I need to write a script that works with zsh and bash,
where I can run 8 given scripts parallel.

The script that I wrote does the job, but once the script is running I can't
stop these 8 subscripts properly. So my question is:
How can I achieve that when I quit my script with CRTL + C, all running subscripts
get killed as well?

My Script:

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "This runs 8 similar versions of giza"

cd giza_google
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_1
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_2
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_3
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_4
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_5
sh runAgent.sh &
cd ..

cd giza_6
sh runAgent.sh 
cd ..
```

Context: "giza" is an agent name and the directory structure should not be changed.
Each folder contains a runAgent.sh that starts a simulation agent.

What I have already tried:

```
trap 'kill $(jobs -p)' EXIT
```

---

```
trap "exit" INT TERM ERR
trap "kill 0" EXIT
```

---

```
#!/bin/bash


trap ctrl_c INT

function ctrl_c() {
    echo "Trapped CTRL_C"
    kill -KILL $PID1 $PID2 $PID3 $PID4 $PID5 $PID6 $PID7 
}

echo "This runs 8 similar versions of giza"

cd giza_google
sh runAgent.sh &
PID1=$!
echo "PID1=" $PID1
cd ..

cd giza
sh runAgent.sh &
PID2=$!
echo "PID2=" $PID2
cd ..

cd giza_1
sh runAgent.sh &
PID3=$!
echo "PID3=" $PID3
cd ..

cd giza_2
sh runAgent.sh &
PID4=$!
echo "PID4=" $PID4
cd ..

cd giza_3
sh runAgent.sh &
PID5=$!
echo "PID5=" $PID5
cd ..

cd giza_4
sh runAgent.sh &
PID6=$!
echo "PID6=" $PID6
cd ..

cd giza_5
sh runAgent.sh &
PID7=$!
echo "PID7=" $PID7
cd ..

cd giza_6
sh runAgent.sh 
cd ..
```

Comment: Note that `sh anything.sh` is a bad idea: it overrides the shebang and forces the script to be executed with `sh`, so even if the script starts with `#!/bin/bash`, bash-specific features that aren't present in `sh` can be unavailable.

Comment: In general, if you've correctly made your script executable (and renamed it to take out the misleading `.sh` extension), you should be able to just run `./runAgent &`, with no `sh` needed.

Comment: bash and zsh are two different shells, and they are not compatible with each other. Tag for one or the other, not both at the same time.

Comment: BTW, all the `cd dir` followed by `cd ..` is bug-prone: What if one of the `cd`s fails? You'll then be running commands in the wrong directory. This is why it's a better practice to use `(cd dir && ...)` -- the `cd` is scoped to the subshell created by the parens, so it's automatically undone on exit.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using **GNU Parallel** to run jobs in parallel. Your whole script becomes:

```
parallel 'cd {} && ./runAgent' ::: giza*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just negate the pgid when you specify the pid to kill.  You should be able to use `$$` as the process group, but sometimes it's convenient to pull the process group id from `ps`.  Try:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "This runs 8 similar versions of giza"

pgid=$(ps -o pgid= $$ | tr -d ' ')
trap 'kill -- -$pgid' 0

for d in giza_google giza giza_{1..6}; do
        (cd $d; sh runAgent) &
done
wait
```

Note that I've changed the name of the script to `runAgent` without the `.sh` suffix.  See [https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/](https://www.talisman.org/%7Eerlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 0):

Insofar as you're using bash, arrays are available to you. "Append to this array" syntax doesn't require all the manual control over numbering involved in having a separate array per child, and you can expand your complete array's contents onto a `kill` command when you want to shut everything down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
agent_pids=( )

(cd giza_a && exec ./runAgent) & agent_pids+=( "$!" )
(cd giza_b && exec ./runAgent) & agent_pids+=( "$!" )
(cd giza_c && exec ./runAgent) & agent_pids+=( "$!" )

wait "${agent_pids[@]}" # let them all finish
kill "${agent_pids[@]}" # shut them all down
```

Using `exec` consumes the subshell that the `cd` was scoped to, and ensures that the PID you're storing is actually that of `runAgent`, not the subshell that started it.

Of course, you can do all this in a function:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shutdown() { kill "${agent_pids[@]}"; }
trap shutdown EXIT

agent_pids=( )

start_agent() {
  for dir; do
    (cd "$dir" && exec ./runAgent) & agent_pids+=( "$!" )
  done
}

start_agent giza_a giza_b giza_c
```

...and you can even use an associative array so you build a map from directories to their associated agents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A agent_pids=( )
shutdown() { kill "${agent_pids[@]}"; }
trap shutdown EXIT

start_agent() {
  for dir; do
    (cd "$dir" && exec ./runAgent) & agent_pids[$dir]=$!
  done
}

start_agent giza_a giza_b giza_c

for agent_name in "${!agent_pids[@]}"; do
  agent_pid=${agent_pids[$agent_name]}
  wait "$agent_pid"; agent_rc=$?
  echo "Agent $agent_name with PID $agent_pid exited with status $agent_rc"
done
```